# PowerBook 145 Screen Issues

Tags: apple, screen

I have a PowerBook 145 that boots up because I can hear the chime but the screen doesn’t come on. The back light is functioning but no data can be viewed on the screen. What can I do?

Comment: Does an external Monitor work?

Comment: I haven’t got one and I don’t believe that there is even a port on the back for an external monitor?

Comment: Right. checked. It actually doesn't. Weird ;) Now that I think about it, there were actually monitor adapters for these models that used the SCSI port...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably an issue with aging capacitors on the display driver board. These become defective over time and need to be replaced.

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kg4ZyFLWYHo) a repair video.

Comment: Thanks. I can get the capacitors for £15. Is that worth it since I don’t know how much the laptop is even worth?

Comment: That's your call.  I wouldn't spend the money on fixing it for resale myself, but if you happen to want to use it...  Although, I had one of those way back in the day and it was barely useable (super slow) even back then.

Comment: Is your goal to use the laptop or at the least enjoy the fact that you own a relatively rare ancient computer? Then 15 is honestly a decent price assuming you have the electronics skills to fix it yourself. If your goal is to make as much money as you can...well, some collectors might pay good for old gray Powerbooks, but there's no good way to ascertain a monetary value.